# Completion of quotient of polynomial ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* uses the following facts on page 35 without proof:

> The completion of $(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2-x^3))_{(x,y)}$ is $k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^2-x^3)$ and that of $(k[x,y]/(xy))_{(x,y)}$ is $k[[x,y]]/(xy)$.

I studied Atiyah-Macdonald's chapter on completions, but I don't know why the above is true. It might be related to the isomorphism $\hat{M}\cong M\otimes_A \hat{A}$ where $A$ is Noetherian and $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, but I'm not sure. I don't have much experience with power series.

Would you please tell me why this is true? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $(R,m)$ is Noetherian local, then $m$-adic completion is exact. Moreover $(f)\widehat{R} \cong \widehat{(f)}$ for any $f \in m$. Thus the exact sequence

$$0 \to (f) \to R \to R/(f) \to 0$$ induces an exact sequence

$$0 \to f\widehat{R} \to \widehat{R} \to \widehat{R/(f)} \to 0$$

Comment: Thank you. I guess you mean $R=k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ and $f=xy$. How do we know that the completion of $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ is $k[[x,y]]$?

Comment: @PeterM: Yes, that is the correct choice for $R$. Your last question I will leave as an (important) exercise - one can show this directly

Comment: @PeterM: Completions satisfy a universal property which makes them unique up to unique isomorphism. If you show that $k[[x,y]]$ has this universal property, you're done.

Comment: @RghtHndSd I used $\hat{A_\mathfrak{m}}\cong\hat{A}$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal of the Noetherian ring $A $. Seems to do the trick.

Comment: @PeterM: What does $\hat{A}$ mean? One takes the completion with respect to an ideal...

Comment: @RghtHndSd $\hat{A}$ is $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion and $\hat{A}_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is its localization at $\mathfrak{m}$. Here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64399/does-completion-commute-with-localization

Comment: @PeterM: This suggests to me that there is some confusion, as did your previous comment. The $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion of $A$ is always a local ring when $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal of $A$.

Comment: @RghtHndSd I'm sorry. Perhaps my notation is confusing. Let $A=k[x,y]$, $\mathfrak{m}=(x,y)$. According to that MO question $k[[x,y]]=\widehat{A}\cong\widehat{A_{\mathfrak m}}=\widehat{k[x,y]_{(x,y)}}$. Is this wrong?

Comment: @PeterM: Ah, now it is clear. $\widehat{A} \cong \widehat{A_m}$ is very much a nontrivial statement as opposed to $\widehat{A} \cong \widehat{A}_m$ which is immediate.

Comment: @zcn This should generalize right? If $(A,\frak{m})$ is a local ring with $\frak{a}$ a proper ideal of $A$ then we should have that $\widehat{(A/\frak{a}}) = \hat{A}/\hat{\frak{a}}$. Or am I mistaken?