# The completion of localization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is the example 5.6.3 in chapter I of Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*. For the reducible variety 
$$
Y = \Big\{ (x,y) \in {\mathbb{A}}^2 ~:~ xy = 0 \Big\}
$$
it follows that the local ring ${\mathcal{O}}_{O,Y} = \Big( {\frac {k[x,y]}{ \langle xy \rangle }} \Big)_{ \langle x, y \rangle }$.

Question 1. What is the most natural way to see that?

Then it follows that ${\widehat{ {\mathcal{O}}_{O,Y} }} \cong {\frac {k[[x, y]]}{ \langle x, y \rangle }}$.

Question 2. Is there a way to see how completion and quotienting are related?

I have not yet gone to the subsequent chapters of Hartshorne yet.

Comment: Not sure what you want exactly, are you stuck are some step in this particular case ? $m=(x,y)$ is a maximal ideal of $R=k[x,y]/(xy)$, any pair of maximal ideal are comaximal, so $R_m=(R/I_m-m)^{-1}R/I_m$ is a local ring (unique maximal ideal) where $I_m= \sum_{a\in R,\exists b\in R-m,ab=0}aR$. Lifting $(x,y)$ to its corresponding maximal ideal of $k[x,y]$, the completion and the quotient by $(xy)$ commute that is $\widehat{R_m}=\varprojlim R_m/m^n \cong (\varprojlim k[x,y]/m^n)/(xy)=k[[x,y]]/(xy)$, same for the localization.

Comment: Can you explain a bit on the expression of $R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ you have there?

Comment: For an integral domain $S$ and a maximal ideal $m$ then $S_m=(S-m)^{-1}S$ is a subring of the fraction field $Frac(S)$, and a local ring. Here $R$ is not an integral domain so maybe (maybe not) some elements will become zero when inverting the elements of $R-m$, that's what $I_m$ is: the kernel of $R\to R_m$, the smallest ideal such that every element of $R/I_m-m$ is not a zero divisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us quote from the text you mention:

> ... Let $Y$ be the algebraic set in $\Bbb A^2$ defined by the equation $xy=0$. ... (Since we haven't yet developed the general theory of local rings of points on reducible algebraic sets, we use an ad hoc definition $\mathcal{O}_{O,Y}=(k[x,y]/(xy))_{(x,y)}$. Thus $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{O,Y}\cong k[[x,y]]/(xy)$.)

Hartshorne admits that he has not developed the relevant theory here, but the concept of a locally regular function on an affine algebraic set and the construction of the local ring at a point goes through without any difficulty: a function which is regular at $O$ can be locally described as a quotient $\frac{f}{g}$ of elements $f,g\in k[x,y]/(xy)$ where $g(O)\neq 0$, and two of these $\frac{f}{g},\frac{f'}{g'}$ are equal iff $fg'=f'g$ on some neighborhood of the origin. It is not hard to see that this is the same construction given by localizing $k[x,y]/(xy)$ at $(x,y)$, the maximal ideal of the origin: we take fractions $\frac{f}{g}$ where $f\in k[x,y]/(xy)$ and $g\in (k[x,y]/(xy))\setminus (x,y)$ and declare $\frac{f}{g}=\frac{f'}{g'}$ iff there's some $u\in (k[x,y]/(xy))\setminus (x,y)$ so that $u(fg'-f'g)=0$. But we may observe that $u$ has a nonzero constant term which means that $fg'-f'g=0$ must actually be true. (Later, we'll see this holds in general for any affine scheme - see Proposition II.2.2 on page 71.)

To see the result about completion, just use the fact that the completion of a noetherian local ring at a maximal ideal is exact ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_of_a_ring#Properties), for instance, though any commutative algebra book will do this for you too). To see how to use this to get the statement you want, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900438/completion-of-quotient-of-polynomial-ring) for instance.